# Python/Pandas how to combine all values in a single column into one list

Tags: python, pandas

For example you have a column like this below:

| Column1 |
| --- |
| adfghb, gad |
| 234rwfa |
| ballbalba |
| 9adfad9, 5432 |
| 99a |

Expected output:

```
list1 = ["adfghb", "gad", "234rwfa", "ballbalba", "9adfad9", "5432", "99a"]
```

Datatype in the column is only string. I need efficient code since actual column is quite huge. I used `for` loop, but takes way too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str` methods outside of Pandas:

```
>>> ', '.join(df['Column1']).split(', ')
['adfghb', 'gad', '234rwfa', 'ballbalba', '9adfad9', '5432', '99a']
```

**Performance**

For 25,000 rows:

```
# @MayankPorwal
%timeit df['Column1'].str.split(', ').explode().tolist()
9.99 ms ± 85.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# @jezrael
%timeit [y for x in df['Column1'] for y in x.split(', ')]
4.25 ms ± 30.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# @Corralien
%timeit  ', '.join(df['Column1']).split(', ')
2.24 ms ± 22.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```
In [1044]: l = df['Column1'].str.split(', ').explode().tolist()

In [1045]: l
Out[1045]: ['adfghb', 'gad', '234rwfa', 'ballbalba', '9adfad9', '5432', '99a']
```